# Microsoft Access save number of query results to a table with date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I just need some help with my Microsoft Access Database

I have a query with results. I want to save the number of results to a table with the date. So I end up having a table like

```
9/04/2015            40
10/04/2015           45
11/04/2015           34
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, because I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a table "date_count" with Schema

```
Date__C  Date/Time
Count    Number
```

then use the following query

```
insert into date_count
(
date__c,count
)
select date(),count(*)
from (SELECT *
      from  calls)
```

the inner query

```
 SELECT *
 from   calls
```

should be replaced by your query

Answer (score 0):

Create and run a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO YourLogTable 
    ( YourDateField, YourCountField )
SELECT 
    Date(), Count(*) 
FROM YourQuery;
```